# Reading data from a custom file extension

Tags: java, matlab, enums, file-type

I am trying to import raw data from an ultrasound system. When it saves the data I want to analyze, it creates a file with it's custom file extension. The systems wiki gives me all of the header data, and the data enumeration. The file extension is a .cvv which is created and used by the ultrasound software.

I know some MATLAB, Java and C++, but I have no idea how to open a custom file type by just using the header and an enumerated type. I'm guessing I have to write some sort of script which imports the data raw data from the file and then organizes it using the variables in the header and enumeration. I would prefer to do it in MATLAB, as I can easily create matrices with the data, but I am open to using the other two languages that I am familiar with.

Header info:

```
struct uFileHeader {
    int type;    // data type (can be determined by file extensions)
    int frames;  // number of frames in file 
    int w;       // width (number of vectors for raw, image width for processed data)
    int h;       // height (number of samples for raw, image height for processed data)
    int ss;      // data sample size in bits
    int ulx;     // roi - upper left (x) 
    int uly;     // roi - upper left (y) 
    int urx;     // roi - upper right (x) 
    int ury;     // roi - upper right (y) 
    int brx;     // roi - bottom right (x) 
    int bry;     // roi - bottom right (y) 
    int blx;     // roi - bottom left (x) 
    int bly;     // roi - bottom left (y) 
    int probe;   // probe identifier - additional probe information can be found using this id   
    int txf;     // transmit frequency in Hz
    int sf;      // sampling frequency in Hz
    int dr;      // data rate (fps or prp in Doppler modes)
    int ld;      // line density (can be used to calculate element spacing if pitch and native # elements is known
    int extra;   // extra information (ensemble for color RF)
};
```

enumeration:

```
enum uData
{
    udtScreen                = 0x00000001,
    udtBPre                  = 0x00000002,
    udtBPost                 = 0x00000004,
    udtBPost32               = 0x00000008,
    udtRF                    = 0x00000010,
    udtMPre                  = 0x00000020,
    udtMPost                 = 0x00000040,
    udtPWRF                  = 0x00000080,
    udtPWSpectrum            = 0x00000100,
    udtColorRF               = 0x00000200,
    udtColorCombined         = 0x00000400,
    udtColorVelocityVariance = 0x00000800,
    udtContrast              = 0x00001000,
    udtElastoCombined        = 0x00002000,
    udtElastoOverlay         = 0x00004000,
    udtElastoPre             = 0x00008000,
    udtECG                   = 0x00010000,
    udtGPS1                  = 0x00020000,
    udtGPS2                  = 0x00040000,
    udtPNG                   = 0x10000000
};
```

The full wiki page is [here](http://www.ultrasonix.com/wikisonix/index.php/Working_with_Data#Exam_6.0.3_and_6.0.4).

Comment: Is the data stored in plain text or binary format? Does the file begin with the header and then a data section?

Comment: Data is stored as a specific filetype created by the software. ex. filename.cvv. Opening it up in any text editor gives me random characters.

Comment: I looked at the wiki and the file format is not clear from that page. Can you upload an example file somewhere? Just make a dump of the background if the data is sensitive.

Comment: Sure! File is [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!Jd0QRRjB!Vg8HmQkCSXGN2YGDm4ulPLWzKL3cT52Te5vbDEMURS8). I also tried writing some c++ code to read the data. You can see what I've gotten so far [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591748/c-how-to-convert-struct-data-into-plaintext)

Comment: I assume you generate the data with a tool from Sonix/Ultrasonix? They have a toolbox for Matlab http://www.ultrasonix.com/wikisonix/index.php/SonixDataTools that can load the data into Matlab. It looks like they have previously provided Matlab functions for loading their data, but it requires a login to see.

Since the data format is not completely specified you need to reverse engineer the format if you want to write your own functions. But this can be a lot of work.

Comment: @Silas I am unable to get access to the matlab. I can now parse the header data, but not the actual transducer data. I assume the enumeration points to an address, but the data that I want should be more than just a single memory address.

Comment: Ok. The uData enum is just an integer indicating the filetype. If you look a the wiki you can see that the .cvv frames are W * H * 2 in size, so you can find the data size from the header. If you are lucky the remaining file after the header is just frames*w*h*2*ss bits. Then you only need to figure the order data is stored - row-major/column-major

Comment: @Silas I think I got it working. I just saved my whole buffer as an array of chars and then parsed each individual char after the header for my data. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Could you write how you did, so others that need to work with the files can see how to do it.